# Does IPv6 have LAN IP addresses (like 192.168.1.5 in IPv4)?

Tags: lan, ipv6

I have read that with IPv6 every device will have its own unique IP address, does that mean in an IPv6 LAN there would be no IP addresses like 192.168.1.5 in IPv4?

Answer (score 3):

Yes and no – IPv6 does *support* private addresses, but their usage is somewhat different from IPv4, and many LANs indeed do not use them at all.

Usually your global address *is* your LAN address – you don't need a separate address type for internal communications when you can just assign global addresses to devices and use those addresses for everything. (It means you no longer need to deal with "hairpin NAT" or "split-view DNS" because both external and internal clients can connect to the same address.)

<sup>(This also used to be true in IPv4, when the Internet was smaller. Some organizations – e.g. MIT – still used global IPv4 addresses for their LANs as recently as 2017.)</sup>

There *is* a "private" address range in IPv6, though – it's the `fd00::/8` range (called the "ULA" range for "unique local address"). However, in most cases it is assigned *in addition to* global addresses, not instead of, so even if your hosts have private addresses for LAN usage, they will *still* have individual global addresses for Internet access to avoid the need for inbound or outbound NAT.

(Often you will see this kind of dual addressing in home LANs, where the global address prefix isn't guaranteed to be permanent, so the home router will provide a private prefix to make sure LAN devices can still communicate while the WAN link goes down.)

Could an IPv6 host have *only* a private address, but not a global one? It's possible – e.g. you might do this when your LAN has no Internet access over v6, or when it's completely impossible to get a global prefix of a reasonable size (e.g. when you're trying to run VMs but your LAN doesn't support prefix delegation). Both 1:1 NAT and 'many-to-1' aka 'masquerading' NAT can be implemented in IPv6, although they're strongly discouraged.

---

Finally, there's a third address type in IPv6 – `fe80::/64` *link-local* addresses, which don't exactly have an equivalent in IPv4. Although technically they're also a type of private address, link-local addresses are not really meant for general LAN usage – they aren't routable the way "normal" private addresses are; their main purpose is to carry internal traffic such as DHCP or mDNS.

Comment: [IPv4 link-local](https://datatracker.ietf.org/doc/html/rfc3927) is `169.254.0.0/16`

Comment: Kind of, but no, that's not equivalent – it's indeed an unroutable prefix but doesn't serve nearly the same purpose (it was defined as a "zero configuration LAN" prefix and almost never used alongside other addresses, so it's practically the opposite of fe80::/64 being an universally present and complementing the routable addresses).

Comment: That property of ipv6 addresses is not unique to link-local, there is general difference on how any non-global-unique addresses are used in ipv4 and ipv6. There are additional considerations that don't stem from the address functional definitions themselves, but from the way various auxiliary protocols are defined: NDP instead of ARP, DHCPv6 cs DHCPv4 and so on. If we leave that difference out, functionally ipv4 and ipv6 link-local are defined alike in the sense that they are configured statelessly and the packets shouldn't be forwarded by gateways.

Comment: Also, don't think link-local ipv6 are always present. For instance, there is no such address on my ipv6-enabled VPS. There is only a single globally-routable address.

Answer (score 1):

IPv6 means that every device has an address on the internet and can be
directly reached. The router does not do
[Network address translation (NAT)](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Network_address_translation),
and there are no local IPv6 addresses (as distinct from global ones).
Although NAT is still technically possible, it's not commonly used.

All that's left from the `192.168.1.x` prefix and its equivalents,
is a 64-bit prefix number that's assigned to the router by the DHCP
server of the ISP, from which are generated the local device addresses.

For more information, see
[Wikipedia IPv6](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6).

Comment: There is a concept of address scope in IPv6. There are link-local addresses (fe80::/10), which function somehow like RFC 1918 private addresses in IPv4 (192.168.0.0/16 is one of them), as they are not routed outside LAN. However, they are used **along** global IPv6 addresses and not **instead** of them, as they are automatically generated on each IPv6 enabled interface. There are also site-local addresses (fec0::/10) that are even more similar to RFC 1918 addresses as they can be subnetted (link-local addresses can't), but this address class is deprecated now.

Comment: @raj the equivalent to rfc1918 private is *fd00::/8* which could be split and forwarded and it essentially took the role of *fec0::*; the *fe80::* block is link-local, like 169.254.0.0/16, for instance, both shouldn't be forwarded by gateways. However, I agree that use of special addresses (non-globally-unique) in IPv6 is a lot different than in IPv4.